# Getting angular FormControl value and update button

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I'm new to angular and using angular FormControl and facing some issue as below.

I just have a input text with required validator. Based on input entered by user and if the text is valid, I want to enable one button. if input text is invalid, I want to disable button.

When running this, disabled button is never getting enabled. Please check and let me know some suggestions.

Here is my code. I'm using angular reactive forms.

sample.html:

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" [formControl]="userName" required>
<p>Value: {{ userName.value }}</p>
<button disabled="(userName.value === '')">{{ userName.value }}</button>
```

Sample.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
})


export class SampleComponent {
 userName = new FormControl('')

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
     console.log("entered")
     console.log(this.userName.getRawValue());
     
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) to dynamically evaluate the expression. By using HTML property, you're passing a string `(userName.value === '')`, which is always a *truthy* value (so, disabled property is always set to true).

Change this `disabled` to `[disabled]`

Then, you can take advantage of the valid or invalid status of the fromControl, which return a boolean, also lets you perform a better or more complex validation.

Change this `[disabled]="(userName.value === '')"` to this `[disabled]="userName.invalid"` or `[disabled]="!userName.valid"`

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" [formControl]="userName" required>
<p>Value: {{ userName.value }}</p>
<button [disabled]="userName.invalid">Click me</button>
```

---

### Bonus tip

Don't use inline required attribute, but set the validators during the input set up.
So, remove the `required` from your HTML and set the input like this:

```js
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...
userName = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

Comment: thankyou so much for bonus tip, im now adding extra validators there.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<button disabled="(userName.value === '')">{{ userName.value }}</button>
```

To this

```
<button [disabled]="userName.value === ''">{{ userName.value }}</button>
```

In Angular, if you put square brackets around an attribute, it will evaluate the code being passed in as Javascript, e.g. `[disabled]="true"`.

If you do not put square brackets around the attribute it will evaluate the code being passed in as a string, e.g. `disabled="true"` is the same as `[disabled]="'true'"`

Therefore in your example, you were passing the string `"(userName.value === '')"` into the `disabled` attribute, instead of having it evaluate the `userName` formControl as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code:

```
userName = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
<button [disabled]="userName.errors?.['required']">{{ userName.value }}</button>
```